# AngualarJS bootstrap Tab set Active item

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set second tab as an active one, unfortunately heading goes off.
Is there anything i am missing?

```html
<tabset>
   <tab disabled="true">
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> First tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         fixed tab content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
   <tab active="true">
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> First tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         First content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
   <tab>
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Second Tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         Second content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: should someone read this code formatting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can not set active to true/false. That way it cannot be changed. Bind it to a variable...

```
<tab active="isActive">
```

and set ...

```
$scope.isActive = true;
```

in your Controller.

And i think you should remove the ¸`<tab-content>` 's. You do not need them.

Answer (score 4):

To extend on Markus' answer, if you just want to set a tab as active (like I do for testing my site) without getting a controller involved you could to this:

```
<tab active="isActive" ng-init="isActive = true">
```

But I wouldn't recomend this in production code as ng-init should hardly ever be used.